# dhcpv6-client Open For Firewalld On Cent-OS 7

Tags: centos, firewalld, dhcpv6

Hi I have checked and unable to find an answer to this already posted.

I have reinstalled Cent-OS 7 on a dedicated server. It uses a template that OVH have (they are the provider of the server) for re installation.

I have manually installed firewalld using yum. However when I have gone to open up ports for the required services I have found :

```
firewall-cmd --list-service
dhcpv6-client ssh
```

I assume the client is to retrieve the IPv6 range via DHCP however upon looking in ifcfg-eth0 I have the following (modified to mask the range):

```
IPV6ADDR=1111:1111:1:1111::1/64
```

SO I assume I will not receive IP's via DHCP. Of course I can understand ssh being open however do I need dhcpv6-client to be open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That port is open by default. If you have a manually configured address, you can always close it again.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I did suspect that was the case but wanted to be sure.